# Положение контента в зависимости от ширины

Tags: html, css, webview, веб-дизайн, viewport

Нужно, чтобы контент, допустим изображение и текст, меняли положение в завистмости от размера окна. Пример: окно в полный экран - слева текст, справа картинка, сжатый по горизонтали (как на мобилках) - картинка сверху, текст снизу.

Comment: Это не фриланс площадка..

Comment: @CblPoK2513 Я знаю, мне просто нужна помощь. Старайтесь делать этот мир лучше. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.image{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .container{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat maiores repellendus eos asperiores. Modi aut ab voluptate quia magni itaque veritatis pariatur consectetur quas rerum.</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ура! Спасибо! Рома, ты лучший! Дай, я тебя обниму!